# Calculate size in Hex Bytes

Tags: size, hex, byte

what is the proper way to calculate the size in hex bytes of a code segment. I am given:

```
IP = 0848    CS = 1488    DS = 1808   SS = 1C80    ES = 1F88
```

The practice exercise I am working on asks what is the size (in hex bytes) of the code segment and gives these choices:

```
A. 3800    B. 1488    C. 0830    D. 0380    E. none of the above
```

The correct answer is A. 3800, but I haven't a clue as to how to calculate this.

Comment: What are Hex Bytes? 1 byte = 2 hex bytes because they need two characters to print in hex?

Comment: @Thilo I'm not sure. I must have missed this section in class as I don't see it in my class notes.

Comment: Shouldn't code segment be the size up to data segment? I.e. `0x1808-0x1488 = 0x0380`.

Comment: And if this is a homework, tag it as one...

Comment: @erikH It's not homework, as the answer is given from a study guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to calculate the length:

- Note CS.  Find the segment register that's nearest to it, but greater.
- Take the difference between the two, and multiply by 0x10 (read: tack on a 0).

In your example, DS is closest.  1808 - 1488 == 380.  And 380 x 10 = 3800.

BTW, this only works on the 8086 and other, similarly boneheaded CPUs, and in real mode on x86. In protected mode on x86 (which is to say, unless you're writing a boot sector or a simple DOS program), the value of the segment register has very little to do with the size of the segment, and thus the stuff above simply doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks! All of the practice exercises are done with architecture 8086 in mind.

Comment: I know this question is a few years old, but to be quite frank I'd argue that the size of the Code Segment is 65536 bytes(or 64kb). What would you say the size of the Code Segment is if CS=DS=ES=SS=2000h (which would be what you'd see in a tiny memory model). Nothing on the 8086 prevents code executing in the data segment (if they happen to overlap)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: If the segments only partly overlap, though, you're probably using a more semantic memory layout. While you _can_ execute data bytes on the 8086, partial overlaps hint that you don't really _want_ to -- that you intend for bytes from that point on to be data (or stack) rather than code. It'd be defeating that to consider those bytes as part of the code segment, even if _technically_ they are.