# Size of the 8086 Code Segment

Tags: assembly, intel, x86-16

I am given the register values for CS, DS, SS, ES, SP, BP, SI, DI, AX, BX, CX, DX. How would I go about finding the size in hex bytes of the Code Segment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate size in Hex Bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509836/calculate-size-in-hex-bytes)

Comment: I happen to disagree with the answer in the duplicate question. I side pretty much with Serge's answer here, except to say that all segment are 64kb. Even if a Segment is equal to 0xFFFF it is still 64kb and wraps around to the bottom of memory.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

8086 is rather outdated now, but some dynosaurus remember about it. It was a 16 bits processor but with 20 bits for the addresses : the 4 segment registers (CS, DS, ES and SS) had values shifted by 4  and the offset were added to that. The total addressable memory was 1 Mbyte.

The maximum size of any segment was 65536 bytes (0x10000). But the actual size of the code segment was not known to the processor. There was no memory protection, and it was allowed to write data in the middle of the code segment (what might be right or wrong depending if programmer knew why :-( ).

There used to be different common memory models (ref :[8086 Memory Model](http://80864beginner.com/Tutorial/Memory-Model.html)):

1. Tiny: CS = DS = SS = ES : the total program used 1 single segment and was limited to 64k bytes
2. Small: one code segment and one data segment. Data and code both used near addressing (16 bits).
3. Compact: one single segment for code, no limit for data : code used near addressing (16 bits), and data used far addressing(32 bits : segment + offset)
4. Medium: one single segment for data, no limit for code
5. Large: no limit for code and for data

So :

- The maximum code of a segment is 64kbytes, but the used size could be less
- the code could use as many segment as needed (for medium and large model) the size of each was less than 64k

Comment: I agree with you for the most part, but I'd say that the size of ANY segment is always 64kb (The segment size on the 8086 can't be changed AFAIK), You say _The maximum size of any segment was 65536 bytes (0x10000)_, I suggest the size of a segment is always equal to 64kb, and as you point out you can't compute how much of that is even used on the 8086. This question appears as a duplicate of another where it is suggested the Code Segment can be computed, and I wholeheartedly disagree.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: What you call a segment is the memory addressable from one base register, and this is indeed 64k on a 8086! What I (and the ref'd question - nice pick for you) call a segment is what the linker declared to be a segment and this one is *limited* to 64k. Now *assuming the program uses small memory model*, and *assuming CS < DS < SS* we can **guess** that code segment extends from CS to DS and data segment extends from DS to SS. But all this could be plain wrong is program used medium or large memory model, not speaking of a custom memory management.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, however from the way the questions are worded here and the other one there is no mention of context (linker) etc. With lack of proper context I fall back to how the processor would see it. Tiny memory model would have all the segments the same but I doubt anyone is going to argue that the Code segment is 0 bytes ;-) . I think that the questions lack clarity and maybe the questions here are not how they were actually given to the original posters.

Comment: As a foot note, I would have considered the context of linker had the question said they were talking about the text and data segments or text and data sections (terminology varies between assembler).

Comment: @MichaelPetch I really no longer remember if my (french) manuals spoke of segments or sections :-) But I loved the 0 byte size segment !